What's the best way of keeping Miniforge up to date?
I know this question hast been asked a lot and you are probably annoyed by it. But what is the best way of keeping Miniforge up to date?
The command I read mostly nowadays is:
mamba update --all

But there is also:
mamba update mamba
mamba update --all

Earlier there was:
(conda update conda)
conda update --all)


I guess the outcome of the conda command would be equivalent to the mamba command, am I correct?
But what is the use of updating mamba or conda, before updating --all?

Besides that there is also the -u flag of the installer:
-u           update an existing installation


What's the use of that and what are the differences in outcome of updating using the installer?

I always do a fresh reinstall after uninstalling once in a while, but that's always a little time consuming since I also have to do all the config stuff. This is of course doable, but it would be nice, if there was one official way of keeping conda up to date.
Also for this I have some questions:

What would be the difference in outcome of a fresh reinstall vs. the -u way vs. the mamba update --all way?
And what is the preferred way?

I also feel it would be great, if the one official way would be mentioned in the docs.
Thanks for elaborating :).

Don't make this into an XY problem: if you have a clean miniconda base, i.e. you don't install anything to it, there should be little issue in updating conda in base. I would try to adress that issue instead

I have a clean conda base and there's nothing installed in there except for mamba. However, if I update only conda (using conda update conda? Or would conda udpate --allbe better?) would this also push python to a newer version?
